# Can I use order of operations (BIDMAS) on any question?

Tags: education

Does [BIDMAS](http://maths-wiki.wikispaces.com/Bidmas) only apply to simple calculations, or can you use them in algebra etc?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: Yes, and the reason why is its always in that order is so that everyone knows how to write euqations to meet things. If those rules werent followed, then simple math could become impossible to decipher.

Example:

$1-2-3=(1-2)-3=-1-3=-4$

But that could also mean

$1-2-3=1-(2-3)=1-(-1)=1+1=2$

The standard order of operations is what keeps our math consistent and understandable.